# Придаточные предложения на «бы» с «не» вместо «ни»

Tags: орфография

Правда, что здесь нужно *ни* использовать:

> Как бы его ни ругала учительница, он всё опаздывал да опаздывал.

но, поскольку здесь есть *а*, надо *не* использовать?

> Как бы стар-забывчив я не стал, а всё равно никогда-никогда не забуду, как в вечёр зимненький мы с Вами в парковых аллеях, вовсю заснеженных, гуляли — молодые, амбициозные.

Мне так из-за 5-го пункта кажется: http://old-rozental.ru/orfografia.php?sid=82#pp82.

Comment: И там и там НИ, поскольку это усиление утверждения.

Answer (score 1):

Как бы ни ругала... - учительница его таки ругала, но он опаздывал. Поэтому НИ, для разделения двух утверждений. Независимо от того, ругала ли учительница его и как ругала, он не переставал опаздывать.

Как бы стар-забывчив я ни стал, я не забуду. Я не забуду - главное, я ни стал второстепенное, поэтому ни. Независимо от того, стану я забывчив или нет, я не забуду. Я НИ стал - разделение.

Я переживаю, что позабуду - как бы стар и забывчив я не стал. Тут связка: если стану стар, то позабуду, - поэтому "не стал".

Comment: С грамматикой все решается проще. Уступительные отношения в СПП не меняются в зависимости от структурных вариантов главной части. А придаточная часть одна и та же (союз КАК БЫ НИ).

Comment: @Sharon как бы я не понял)

Comment: Как бы почему не понимаете?)  Придаточное:  Как бы стар-забывчив я ни стал...  Главное: а не забуду/но не забуду/не забуду. Варианты-с.  Назначайте любой.

Comment: @Sharon то есть вы хотите сказать, что надо - как бы забывчив я ни стал?

Comment: Ну да! А вы разве не так думаете) Забавно!

Comment: @Sharon тогда так.

Comment: Ну вот. Приятно иметь дело с умным человеком)